# DynamoDB DeleteItem Expressions not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm getting a really weird error when I try to preform a DeleteItem with expressions. Can anyone help?

Thanks

```
{
    "TableName": "MyTable",
    "Key": {
        "SESSION": {
            "S": "1E3E181C-1238-D168-725D-9B0FE7F5EA3E"
        }
    },
    "FilterExpression": "#X < :X ",
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {
        "#X": "ttl"
    },
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":X": {
            "N": "1502905189"
        }
    }
}

// RESULT

Array
(
    [__type] => com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException
    [message] => ExpressionAttributeNames can only be specified when using expressions
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delete item` should not contain `FilterExpression`. If you would like to delete the item based on some condition, you can use `ConditionExpression` to specify the condition.

```
"ConditionExpression" : "#X < :X "
```

Please replace the `FilterExpression` with `ConditionExpression`.